# Error installing mix in LinuxMint Rosa 17.03

Tags: mix

I followed the instructions here:
https://gavofyork.gitbooks.io/turboethereum/content/chapter1.html

For installing mix on my machine. The last step threw some errors saying I have some unmet dependencies (`sudo apt-get install mix`). I read in a thread in stackexchange that for ubuntu this has been changed to

```
sudo apt-get install mix-ide
```

Running that, the installation worked. But now it shows this error:

> mix-ide: error while loading shared libraries: libsolidity.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Mix is no longer supported.   It was discontinued several months back and the TurboEthereum guide you refer to is probably a year out of date.

Some alternatives are suggested at http://solidity.readthedocs.org

Comment: I wasted a lot of time tryin to install mix! Thanks Bob.